# List of PrimeFactors without powers

Tags: list-manipulation, number-theory

If I do

```
FactorInteger[120]
```

I get

```
{{2, 3}, {3, 1}, {5, 1}}
```

which is correct of course, but how do I get it as or change it to

```
{2, 2, 2, 3, 5}
```

?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
ConstantArray[#[[1]], #[[2]]] & /@ FactorInteger[120] // Flatten

{2, 2, 2, 3, 5}
```

Comment: You can make this even more slick with `ConstantArray @@@ FactorInteger[120] // Flatten`

Comment: In version 10.2 or later you could also use `Table @@@ FactorInteger[120] // Flatten`

Comment: This is what I love about this site -- there's always better ways of doing things!